# How to get information from 3 separate tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, merge, relational-database

I have a table called users that stores user information and each user can have multiple business accounts that are stored in separate tables.

**Models:**

User:

```
id
name
```

UserProviderAccount:

```
id
user_id
business_name
business_tell
business_address
```

UserCompanyAccount:

```
id
user_id
company_name
company_size
```

UserInfluencerAccount:

```
id
user_id
name
website
follower_count
```

Table relations:

User :

```
public function providers(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserProviderAccount::class);
}

public function companies(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserCompanyAccount::class);
}

public function influencers(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserInfluencerAccount::class);
}
```

I want to display the user's business accounts of all three types at once.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to load and call the relationships as follows:

`UserController`: sample controller and function

```
public function show(User $user) {
    //Here we will load all of the relationships for the specific user
    $user->load('providers', 'companies', 'influencers');

    //Assign the providers from user->providers
    $providers = $user->providers;
    
    //Assign the companies from user->companies
    $companies = $user->companies;
    
    //Assign the influencers from user->influencers
    $influencers = $user->influencers;

    //Send all of the data to the view
    return view('users.show', compact('user', 'providers', 'companies', 'influencers'));
}
```

**users.show View:** *simplified version to show you concept.*

```
<p>{{$user->name}}</p>

<p>The providers:</p>
<ul>
    @foreach($providers as $provider)
        <li>{{$provider->business_name}}</li>
        <li>{{$provider->business_tell}}</li>
        <li>{{$provider->business_address}}</li>        
    @endforeach
</ul>

<p>The companies:</p>
<ul>
    @foreach($companies as $company)
        <li>{{$company->company_name}}</li>
        <li>{{$company->company_size}}</li>     
    @endforeach
</ul>

<p>The influencers:</p>
<ul>
    @foreach($influencers as $influencer)
        <li>{{$influencer->name}}</li>
        <li>{{$influencer->website}}</li>
        <li>{{$influencer->follower_count}}</li>        
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @KGG but in the situation where the number of user's business accounts is very large and I want to do this, it might be unreasonable to load all the records at once.

Comment: @Mehdi explain more what you want to do, do you just want to get the counts? like count how many influencers / companies / providers?

Comment: My application is a web service that has an api that sends a list of user business accounts to the client.
On the client side, all three types of accounts need to be displayed in a merged list

Comment: after you load the relationships do the following **dd($user->toArray());** this will give you an array of the user, and all related relationships, then you format it as you like to send to the clients.